# Redis output to Python Variable

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to retrofit a bit of code a friend gave me. This is what a snippet of what I have right now:

```
print 'Message is', message
md5Hash = hashlib.md5(message).hexdigest()
print 'Hash is', md5Hash
tempName = md5Hash + '.glados.wav'
doneName = 'ok-' + md5Hash + '.done.wav'
for f in os.listdir(filesPath):
    if f[-4:] in ('.wav', '.mdd'):
            os.remove(filesPath + os.sep + f)
```

Right now, it is receiving the "message" variable from an argument passed when the script is run.  What I would like to do is take the output from a Redis command:

```
LPOP myList
"one"
```

and put that "one" as the "message" python variable.

There's probably an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Um... use [`redis-py`](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)?

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
message = r.lpop("myList")
# ...
```